# Alternative to using 'left only' rows in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working with bootstrap, but there's just a few things that confuse me about the grid management.

In this case, my grid structure tends to go (as an example)..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="homeBox">

       </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="homeBox">

       </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

(Apologies for poor formatting)

This works fine for full width elements (col-xs-12), however if i'm trying to have two elements next to each other (col-xs-6) with a row before adding the content, they simply touch each other in the middle, and if adding a background it makes it seem like one element. [Here's a JFiddle showing what I mean.](https://jsfiddle.net/96se4kop/) If i was to add a row before the homebox, it makes them touch. I can also just not add a row after the col-xs-x, but then it won't align correctly to the other full width elements on the page.

In sites I'm working on, I workaround this by adding a 'leftRow/rightRow' class for small devices onwards, but this seems a bit of a bodged way of doing it.

What's the correct way to approach this?
Cheers.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: If you don't want them to touch but stay aligned, you could just make them col-xs-5 both and put col-xs-2 in the middle, but that depends if you're ok with a wider gap in between...

Comment: What do you mean by "they touch each other"? In the JFiddle link it is working properly...

Comment: He means when he adds row classes like in his code. (The code and fiddle are not the same)...